# IDLE - recompile changed code

Tags: python, compilation, python-idle

I can't seem to force IDLE to recompile code. Here's my simple design:

class A and B, B imports A

When I change A, then run B, IDLE doesn't seem to recompile A and run the old version of A.

How can I fix this? :\

Comment: Hmmm have you tried deleting the *.pyc/*.pyo file that python creates when importing a module? That might force it to recompile. (Say you have A.py, and A.pyc, delete A.pyc)

Comment: No it seems that it's saving the compiled version in cache somewhere. Deleting the pyc file did not do anything (it actually didn't even recompile class A because it didn't create a new A.pyc file)

Comment: what system and python version are you running?

Comment: windows 7 and python 2.7

Comment: Ok, I'll try and see if I can replicate this issue.

Comment: Maybe this [python correspondence](http://bugs.python.org/issue2755) will help. (or maybe not). Scroll down about halfway. I *think* he is dealing with a similar issue to you.

Comment: Can you go ahead and post what you did to fix the problem as an answer? That way it will be there for anyone else who runs into a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

The answer on the [python tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue2755) was that someone was starting IDLE with a icon with startup property `/usr/bin/idle-python2.5 -n`.  The key issue is the presence of `-n`, which says to run user code in the IDLE process.  So when B imported A after the first run, A was in sys.modules of the IDLE process.  Without `-n`, IDLE runs user code in the editor (F5) in a new, separate process, where A has to be re-imported from the file.  Jin apparently had the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have **to manually force save on A** (CTRL+S)
And then run B (this will prompt you to save B too)
IF A has changed since last time it should recompile.